# Как организовать авторизацию пользователя

Tags: php

Пишу регистрацию/авторизацию пользователей. При написании возник вопрос: А как после того как пользователь зарегистрировался/вошёл на сайт хранить его данные, чтобы он больше не вводил свои данные и оставался в системе? Т.е понятно что тупо хранить логин и пароль в куках это не есть хорошо. Их можно украсть и получить доступ. Был вариант с идентификатором аккаунта и устройства, но понял что это то же самое - украдёшь, и аккаунт у тебя. Такая же ситуация если  я просто буду давать уникальный идентификатор. Вопрос в том, как организовать хранение данных так, чтобы пользователь только один раз ввёл свои данные и оставался в системе, и при этом максимально безопасно. Надеюсь понятно обьяснил. Если нужны какие-либо уточнения - спрашивайте. В интернете инфы не нашёл, только о том как организовать саму регистрацию.

Comment: уникальный идентификатор, который регулярно меняется

Comment: "В интернете инфы не нашёл, только о том как организовать саму регистрацию" - тебе продали поддельный интернет. Требуй деньги назад и купи нормальный, у официального дилера

Answer (score 1):

Данные храните в бд, шифруйте пароль.
Почитайте про сессии
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php